# Need to set PopupWindow position as per screen

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow, popupmenu, android-popupwindow

I want to set PopupWindow same as screen. Need to set **PopupWindow arrow** and **message more button** to opposite same direction.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_chat_options, null);
mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
customView,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.CustomAnimationTopToBottom);
mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

View view_popup_notification = customView.findViewById(R.id.view_popup_notification);

final View view = mPopupWindow.getContentView();
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView,
0,
-(anchorView.getMeasuredHeight() + customView.getMeasuredHeight()),
(from == 1) ? Gravity.NO_GRAVITY : Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
```

[image]

Comment: ok, and what is a problem?

Comment: I'm trying to set PopupWindow arrow and Recyclerview Item three dots arrow to same direction in all cases(change item width as per message text size) but not getting success.

Comment: I've already read that from the question, but what is a problem for you to do that?

Comment: What should be set in X?

mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchorView,
                0,
                -(anchorView.getMeasuredHeight() + customView.getMeasuredHeight()),
                Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);

Comment: that needs experimenting, but I'd start with minus half of the popup view width